# Creating a table for the ADF- Test

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am modelling with data set and I want to perform Augmented Dickey-Fuller unit root test (ADF test) with vars package. In this example I have three series with names "lnRM3" "lnRGDP" , "R". So my intention is to do ADF-test and put results in one table for R-Markdown. How do can I creat a table with the three Teststatistics, deterministic terms and the c-value?

Comment: Your question would improve if you would try to do it yourself or at least stareted somewhere. Try running the test and saving its `summary` into and object and see wether you can use some part sof it in the table (see `str()`).

Comment: thanks I´ve found a way how it worked out